# Domain of definition of sum of random variables

Tags: probability, combinatorics, measure-theory

If $X$ is a random variable over the sample space $S_1$ and $Y$ is a random variable over the sample space $S_2$, then how can we define the domain sample space of the random variable $X+Y$. please explain the concept. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could it be a Cartesian product? For example, $X$ is the weight of a person on earth, and $Y$ is the height of a person on earth, then the possible weight height combinations are the Cartesian product of the two?

Comment: You don't add random variables defined on different spaces. $X_Y$ is defined only when $X$ and $Y$ are defined on the same space. If you are talking about construction of a suitable space on which $X$, $Y$ and $X+Y$ are all defined, then  the answer depends on how you want  $X$ and $Y$ to be related. If you want them  to be independent you can use the product of the sample spaces.

Comment: If we take $X$ as a binomial random variable with parameter $n_1,p$ and $Y$ as another binomial random variable with parameter $n_2,p$, where both $X, Y$ are independent then what is the domain of random variable $X+Y$.

Comment: The question as is, doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Formally, random variables are functions from some probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{G},\mathbb{P})$ to a sample space $S$.

So, let 
$$X : \Omega \rightarrow S_1 $$
and 
$$Y : \Omega \rightarrow S_2 $$
be random variables.

Before you can define $X + Y$, you need to clarifiy, how you interpret the "+"-symbol. This is done by defining some algebraic operation on the Cartesian product of $S_1$ and $S_2$.
$$ + : S_1 \times S_2 \rightarrow S_3.  $$
Here, $S_3$ is a new, nonempty set, which contains expressions of the form $X(\omega) + Y(\omega)$ for $\omega \in \Omega$.

If $S_1,S_2 \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, then the obvious choice for $"+"$ is the normal addition of numbers and the obvious choice of $S_3$ is $S_3 = \mathbb{R}$. This is done without speaking about it in practise.

If $S_1$ and $S_2$ are more abstract sets, then you have to explicitly define what algebraic operation you mean by the  $"+"$-symbol and what $S_3$ is supposed to be, before you can continue. You have total freedom in choosing $"+"$ and $S_3$, though in many situations some choices are obviously the natural ones.

Comment: In your question, you called your sample space $S$ and not $X$.

Comment: Also, in my answer I covered the case of real numbers as well.

Comment: According to my question, $X$ is a random variable from probability space $(S_1, \mathcal{G},\mathbb{P})$ to real number. According to your probability space, $\Omega$ is sample space, not $S_1$

Comment: You are right. Let me correct this by adding another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$ X : S_1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$ and
$$ Y : S_2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $$ be random variabes with sample spaces $(S_1, \mathcal{A}_1, \mathbb{P}_1)$ and $(S_2, \mathcal{A}_2, \mathbb{P}_2)$. Then the sample space for the random variable $Z := X+Y$ can be defined in a canonical way by constructing the product space $(S, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$ of $(S_1, \mathcal{A}_1, \mathbb{P}_1)$ and $(S_2, \mathcal{A}_2, \mathbb{P}_2)$.

$$(S, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P}) : = (S_1 \times S_2, \mathcal{A}_1 \otimes \mathcal{A}_2, \mathbb{P}_1 \otimes \mathbb{P}_2)$$.

Here, $S := S_1 \times S_2$ denotes the Cartesian product of $S_1$ and $S_2$. Moreover, $\mathcal{A}_1 \otimes \mathcal{A}_2$ and $\mathbb{P}_1 \otimes \mathbb{P}_2$ are the canonical produt sigma algebra and product measure on $S_1 \times S_2$. Now
$$ Z : S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \quad (s_1, s_2) \mapsto Z((s_1,s_2)) := X(s_1) + Y(s_2) $$ is well-defined.

Also, in formulating your question, take care to respect the common notation conventions in probability theory. Sample spaces are usually denoted with $\Omega_i$ and not $S_i$. Furthermore, always specify the range of your random variables (in your case $\mathbb{R}$).